# TreeView how to select 2nds tr in table with css to set BackColor for complete Parent Nodes rows

Tags: asp.net, css, treeview, css-selectors

I've been trying to find the answer to this with tips on other posts
[CSS Selector picker/finder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233809/css-selector-picker-finder)
and the closest partial solution I found to do what I want to do is this:
http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-set-change-treeview-parent-node.html

All I need is to set the background color for all the Parent Nodes to #F0F0F0
as you can see in the link above, the line below will only set background color for the parent area, but no for the complete row . I want to have all the Parent Nodes rows with same background color.

```
<ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" BackColor="#F0F0F0"/>
```

I also tried different combinations of nth-child including the line below but it does not work:

```
table.trvFileTree tr:nth-child(2)
{
background-color: #F0F0F0;

}
```

I've used Dom Inspector plugin and as you can see I want all the 2nd trs to have an specific background color.

Also, I've tried to get full path of the second tr selector by using firebug :

```
html body form#form1 div div.fullWidthWrp div.InnerfullWidth div.LCol div.InnerLCol div#trvFileTree.treeViewDim div#trvFileTreen0Nodes table tbody tr
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Note: could not post screenshots here on stackoverflow since it needs more than 10 reputation points. However, I posted the screenshot of what I need on droplr image share site: http://d.pr/i/OVIp

UPDATE (the code below is almost exactly the same as my code, but I decided just to put code for the treeview so that code only shows what it needs to be done):

1) This is the complete code for the TreeviewExample.aspx 
    **ideone.com/3PXbSE**

2) This is the complete rendered markup for TreeviewExample.aspx 
    **ideone.com/wpctLP**

3) This is the screenshot of the browser view of TreeviewExample.aspx 
    **d.pr/i/8ni6**

As you'll see the complete code on #2) is almost the same as the one rendered below (has same table structure)

The markup below is part of the code generated by the treeview control and shows the Parent node rows that I want to have with different background color: (copied from firebug with only some of the important nodes expanded so that markup is easier to read)

```
        <div id="trvFileTree" class="treeViewDim" style="width: 100%;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <tr style="height: 0px;">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="trvFileTreen0Nodes" style="display: block;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height: 0px;">
                <tr> <%--This row contains a parent node, and I want to set the background color for all the row--%>
                <tr style="height: 0px;">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="trvFileTreen1Nodes" style="display: block;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="height: 0px;">
                    <tr> <%--This row also contains a parent node, and I want to set the background color for all the row--%>
                    <tr style="height: 0px;">
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;"> <%--These tables contain child nodes--%>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;">
        </div>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;">
        <div id="trvFileTreen5Nodes" style="display: none;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="height: 0px;">
                    <tr>
                    <tr style="height: 0px;">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width: 0;">
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you were a bit more clear about what you mean by "I want all the 2nd trs to have an specific background color." Are you saying you want all of the child leaf notes to have the same color as the parent node?  What do you mean by "complete row" in your second paragraph? The example you refer to is a TreeView and not a DataTable.

Comment: I was going to add some screenshots to make it easier to understand, but stackoverflow did not allow me to upload the images. As I mentioned before, I want the complete row for each Parent Node to have a background color. The treeview control is rendered my multiple tables, and in all the tables generated by the .net treeview control I noticed that the 2nd tr is the one that contains each Parent Node. I added an additional example above directly from the code rendered (copied from firebug)

Comment: have you looked in Firebug to see what styles are actually being applied. Your `nth-child()` looks like it should work, so perhaps it's being overridden by other styles. Firebug's CSS inspector will give you a full list of all styles for a given element including those that are valid but overridden (it shows them crossed out). Also, have you tried using `nth-of-type()` rather than `nth-child()`?

Comment: @Spudley thanks for your help. I uploaded the screenshot from firebug dom inspector at dropler image share site: http://d.pr/i/OVIp . There you can see all the Parent nodes that I need to style.

Comment: the code you've copied from firebug isn't very helpful; because you didn't expand everything the copy+paste has given invalid html. Maybe you could paste the actual code for the table (from 'view source' rather than firebug?) and your CSS into an example page on jsBin or jsFiddle; then we'd be able to see exactly what you've got and be able to edit to and show you how to fix it.

Comment: Yes I looked on firebug what styles were applied. Currently I have the style below showing on firebug as applied to the 2nd trs, but the style below also adds the background color to all rows for children nodes, and I need to add background only to all Parent node rows.: #trvFileTree tr:first-child + tr 
{
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

Comment: @Spudley UPDATE (the code below is almost exactly the same as my code, but I decided just to put code for the treeview so that code only shows what it needs to be done): 
1) This is the complete code for the TreeviewExample.aspx
http://ideone.com/3PXbSE
2) This is the complete rendered markup for TreeviewExample.aspx
http://ideone.com/wpctLP
3) This is the screenshot of the browser view of TreeviewExample.aspx
http://d.pr/i/8ni6

As you'll see the complete code on #2) is almost the same as the one rendered below (has same table structure)

Answer (score 0):

I've something for you if I understand your question.

try this out :

```
table tr:not(:nth-child(2n)){
  background-color: #F0F0F0;   
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmY5e/1/)

Sources :

- [CSS3 : not() selector](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/) and   [nth-child with mod (or modulo) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127814/nth-child-with-mod-or-modulo-operator)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your solution and is changing the styling of other tables on the site, but no the rows that I want to style on the treeview. I updated the post, and added a clear example of the Parent node rows that I want to stye. I also tried to do something similar with tr:nth-child(odd) and tr:nth-child(even) but it did not work either.